# How to update the Text in flutter from List

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-application

I have a `Card` widget.

Inside the `Card` widget I have `Text` widget and `Raised Button` widget.

I need to change the `Text` every time the `Button` is pressed, using an entry from a `List` which contains, for example, a list of names

```
void name=["Ali","mike","jack"]
```

On the first click, the `Text` will show "Ali", then the next click will show "mike", and so on.

How can I do this in Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. first define your array as you mention
2. define value default
3. make looping on press

for detail code can refer to this code

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List data = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
  int i = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              data[i],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            i = (i + 1) % data.length;
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setState to update the value. And to get the correct name in the list you just write `name[i]` where i is the index